# SQL. I need to append a set of strings to each value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using  Micorsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 08

I have a query that pulls a bunch of tables together into 2 columns. A list of user Codes in Column A and a list of to letter codes in Column B

```
ColA     ColB

user1 aa

user1 ab

user2 aa

user2 cc
```

So this represents what systems each user has access to. But I need to attach country codes to each of these codes before I can insert it back into a different table. So if I had five countries:

IE,GB,IT,FR,US

Id Like to Replace the first row from above with:

```
ColA     ColB

user1 IE.aa

user1 GB.aa

user1 IT.aa

user1 FR.aa

user1 US.aa
```

And so on for each other unique User/Code combo.I can have all these countries in a separate table easily enough if that makes it easier.

Kind Regards,
Colm

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one to one correspondence between users, codes and countries, it's an easy thing to do.

```
 SELECT ColA, CONCAT(ColB, '.', ColC) as identifier
 FROM SourceTable
```

Replace SourceTable with your table, and add a country code column and call it colC.  Or replace ColC with whatever you name it.

edit follows:  With a one to one correspondence between users and codes, but one to many with users and countries try this:

```
 Users
 ---------------------
 UserID
 UserCode


 Countries
 ----------------------
 CountryCode
 UserID
```

(UserID in Countries is a foreign key to UserID in Users.)  Then you query goes like this:

```
 Select u.UserID, CONCAT(u.UserCode, '.', c.CountryCode) AS result
 FROM Users u
 JOIN Countries c
 ON c.UserID = u.UserID
```

Name the "result" column to be something more descriptive

Comment: Its a one to one between users and codes but not between countries. So for each user/code combo there will be 72 country tags that need to be appended.

Answer (score 1):

If, as per your example, every country is going to be attached to every user then this would work. You just need to create a separate `country` table to hold all the countries.

```
;with cte_users (ColA, ColB)
AS
(
    -- Whatever your current query is
)
SELECT u.ColA, c.country_code + '.' + u.ColB
FROM cte_users u
INNER JOIN country c
ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is an entry per user per country you can `cross apply` the country list to the user table:

```
CREATE TABLE #country ( code CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #country
        ( code )
VALUES  ( 'IE'),('GB'),('IT'),('FR'),('US')

CREATE TABLE #user (name VARCHAR(50), usercode VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #user
        ( name, usercode )
VALUES  ( 'user1', 'aa' )

SELECT 
u.name, c.code + '.' + u.usercode
FROM #user u
CROSS APPLY #country c
```

Comment: Ahh yes ok. This looks like what I'm trying to do alright. I'll give that a shot. Thanks

Comment: Can I have a green check :)